# Given $M$ be a $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix with $p$ positive eigenvalues and $q$ negative eigenvalues. Prove $M=AA^H - BB^H$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question:

Given $M$ be a $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix with $p$ positive eigenvalues and $q$ negative eigenvalues. Prove $M=AA^H - BB^H$ where $A$ is a $n \times p$ matrix and $B$ is a $n \times q$ matrix. Also, rank$(A)=p$ and rank$(B)=q$.

My Attempt:

I use spectral decomposition to write $U^HMU=D$. Then, I split $D$ as $D_p$ with $p$ eigenvalues as its diagonal elements and $D_q$ with $q$ as its diagonal elements. We have $U^HMU=D_p +D_q$ and then $M=UD_pU^H + UD_qU^H$.

Help:

I think I am on the right road but I do not know how to proceed to write $UD_pU^H$ as $AA^H$ and $UD_qU^H$ as $BB^H$. Also, I do not know how to present neatly about the rank of matrices $A$ and $B$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: You're basically done, you just need  $D_p = \sqrt{D_p} (\sqrt{D_p})^H$ and also note what happens if you have $UD_pU^H$ where $D_p$ has $q$ zeros on the diagonal, you can rewrite this in the form requested by seeing which rows and columns get multiplied with a non-zero diagonal entry. The full rank will come from the fact that the columns of $U$ are full rank for the non-zero diagonal entries in $D$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
U D_p U^H = U\sqrt{D_p}\sqrt{D_p}^H U^H = \cdots = AA^H
$$
Note that what we want for the second part is $BB^H = -UD_qU^H$ (the sign is important here).  The rank of $A$ and $B$ are the same as that of $D_p$ and $D_q$.

Comment: So, we can just let $A=U\sqrt{D_p}$? and $B=U\sqrt{D_q}$? and the negative sign is due to $\sqrt{-1} \times \sqrt{-1} = -1$?

Comment: That's right for $A$.  For $B$, what we want is $B = U \sqrt{- D_q}$.  Note that $-D_q$ is a matrix with non-negative entries.

Comment: Thank you, Omn and user256! I get where I am stuck and I work it out.